# invalid read of size 8 only when rehashing hash table in c

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, hashtable

The invalid read occurs in my HTSize function in the code but it also happens in other functions.The issue occurs only when the hash table gets rehashed.It propably has to do with my HTCreate function but Im not really sure.

I ' ve tried using malloc and calloc but nothing works out.

```
typedef char* KeyType;
typedef int HTItem;
typedef struct node{
    KeyType key;
    HTItem item;
    struct node *next;
}List;
typedef struct {
    List *head;
}TableEntry;
typedef TableEntry *HTHash;


int TABLESIZE = 10;

HTHash HTCreate(void)
{
//malloc
//      int i;
//      HTHash table = (HTHash)malloc(TABLESIZE*sizeof(TableEntry));
//      for(i=0;i<TABLESIZE;i++)
//          table[i].head = NULL;
//      return table;
//calloc    
        return calloc(TABLESIZE, sizeof(TableEntry));
}

int HTSize(HTHash hash)
{
    int i,count=0;
    List *temp; 
    for(i=0;i<TABLESIZE;i++)
    {
        if(hash[i].head != NULL)
        {
            count++;
            temp = hash[i].head->next;
            while(temp != NULL)
           {
                count++;
                temp = temp->next;
           }
        }   
    }
    return count;   
}

void HTInsert(HTHash hash, KeyType key, HTItem item)
{
    float a = 0.0;
    int index = h(key);
    int i;
    List *NewNode = (List*)malloc(sizeof(List));
    NewNode->key = key;
    NewNode->item = item;
    NewNode->next = NULL;
    if(hash[index].head == NULL)
        hash[index].head = NewNode;
    else
    {
        if(!strcmp(hash[index].head->key,key))
            hash[index].head->item = item;
        else
        {
            while(hash[index].head->next != NULL)
            {
                if(!strcmp(hash[index].head->next->key,key))
                {
                    hash[index].head->next->item = 
item;
                    break;
                }
                hash[index].head->next = hash[index].head- 
>next->next;
            }
            if(hash[index].head->next == NULL)
                hash[index].head->next = NewNode;
        }
    }
    a = (1.0 * HTSize(hash))/ TABLESIZE;
    if(a>=0.9)
    {
        printf("hash table is rehashing!\n");
        HTRehash(hash); 
    }
}

void HTRehash(HTHash hash)
{
    int i;
    HTHash temp = hash;
    int n = TABLESIZE;
    TABLESIZE = 2 * TABLESIZE;
    hash = HTCreate();
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        List* list = temp[i].head;
        while(list!=NULL)
        {
            HTInsert(hash,list->key,list->item);
            list = list->next;
        }
    }
}
```

In HTSize running it with valgrind it gives me the "invalid read of size 8" 3 times.

Comment: compile without optimization `-O0` and with debug info `-ggdb` and re-run valgrind, it will spot the exact line that case problem

Answer (score 2):

Your problem seems to be that you call `HTRehash` with a single pointer. Then you reallocate the hash table, but now you cannot return this new memory.

You must either call it with a double pointer, so the new memory will be available to the caller, or you must return the new pointer. The latter is more simple, in outline:

```
HTHash HTRehash(HTHash hash)
{
    //...
    hash = HTCreate();
    //...
    return hash;
}
```

I also note that you do not release the old hash table.

Comment: i tried them both and things didn't work.I also tried my HTInsert with a double pointer  and things went really bad.Thanks for the help though.

Comment: You don't show how you call your functions (e.g. `main`) so I can't tell if your calls and return value handling are correct.

Comment: inside main: (HTHash Table = HTCreate(); HTInsert(Table,"abc",10);)When i used double pointer in insert i put '&Table'.Keep in mind that the code doesn't work only when I rehash so those functions work fine with a steady tablesize(when I put the double pointer htinsert wasn't working though).